# Properly formatting foreach and if statement

Tags: php, json, for-loop, if-statement, foreach

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here, or if this is even formatted improperly all together. I am getting an error on line 3.

```
foreach($pge['feats'] as $val) {
} if ($val['name'] == 'wins' && $val['value'] == '1')
    foreach ($val['value'] == '1' as $count) {
        echo count($count);
}
```

Here's another way I tried...

```
foreach($pge['feats'] as $val)
 if ($val['name'] == 'wins' && $val['value'] == '1')
    foreach ($val['value'] == '1' as $count) {
        echo count($count);
}
```

Here's some of the json i'm using. I have several files that will look like this with different values for the wins/value object. My statement will go through each one and check for the wins value to be "1", and then add up the total "1" values together..

Partial contents of my $pge json

```
{
  "playerCount": "2",
  "remote": "0",
  "feats": [
    {
      "name": "score",
      "value": "32"
    },
    {
      "name": "wins",
      "value": "0"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() - line 3

Comment: Don't you find your typo ??  `foreach($pge['feats'] as $val) {
}`

Comment: Your curly braces wrong end

Comment: I've moved the braces around also and still got the error. This is another way I had it.

`
    foreach($pge['feats'] as $val) {
     if ($val['name'] == 'wins' && $val['value'] == '1')
     foreach ($val['value'] == '1' as $count) {
      echo count($count);
    }}
`

Comment: You need to pass an array as the first argument for foreach but you passed a boolean instead

Comment: An example of $pge['feats'], and explaining briefly what you are trying to achieve (desired output) may help this question.

Comment: I've edited the post. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

function game_won(array $game) {
  $win = false;
  foreach($game['feats'] as $val) {
    if ($val['name'] == 'wins' && $val['value'] == '1') {
      $win = true;
    }
  }
  return $win;
}

function sum_game_wins(array $games) {
  $sum = 0;
  foreach($games as $game) {
    if(game_won($game)) {
      $sum++;
    }
  }
  return $sum; 
}

$game_1 =<<<JSON
{
  "playerCount": "2",
  "remote": "0",
  "feats": [
    {
      "name": "score",
      "value": "32"
    },
    {
      "name": "wins",
      "value": "1"
    }
  ]
}
JSON;

$game_2 =<<<JSON
{
  "playerCount": "2",
  "remote": "0",
  "feats": [
    {
      "name": "score",
      "value": "32"
    },
    {
      "name": "wins",
      "value": "0"
    }
  ]
}
JSON;

$game_1 = json_decode($game_1, TRUE);
$game_2 = json_decode($game_2, TRUE);

var_dump(sum_game_wins(array($game_1, $game_2)));
```

Output:

```
int(1)
```

Comment: This almost works, however instead of counting the values that equal "1" it is displaying all the 1's and 0's (wins and losses) in this format..

1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

This shows 4 wins, which is correct. How can I get it to only count those 4 "1"s as the number 4?

Thank you

Comment: @KJThaDon please edit your question to include more sample data and the desired output.  I've tried to expand and guess at your sample data, and with that, it works for me.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information, I'm confusing myself here also lol...

The desired output would be a single integer that calculates all the wins as one number, just like you are getting. The thing I am missing is that, each player has their own json file for every single game they have played, and each file has the name-wins / value(0 or 1) in their file. I think the reason I am only getting each win value separately is because the values are from multiple files...I have a player with 4 wins out of 26 games... Each one of those 26 games has the win value, and 4 have it as "1"

Comment: With this code, I am able to get that player's total wins to show as "1 1 1 1" 

if there was a way I could get it to add them together, that would be great, but the values are coming from separate files...

Comment: $win_total = 0;  
foreach($pge['feats'] as $val) {
  if ($val['name'] == 'wins' && $val['value'] == '1') {
    $win_total++;
  
echo $win_total;
}
}

Comment: I'm going to upload a single file with everything I have to recreate the exact issue. Appreciate the help

Comment: @KJThaDon, code vvriting service is it?  You'll need to probably do some more adaptations: https://paste.ee/p/Fls65

Comment: Didn't think I was that far off, just trying to learn...i'll take a look, seems like I was way off by looking at the code..

Comment: @KJThaDon, no, not far off, you'll likely vvant some efficiencies, such as reusing your connection if you are pulling down so much data.  Use indenting for your loops and conditionals, it really helps vvhen reading the code, and you are less likely to create logic errors.

Comment: Thank you sir, really appreciate it! Is there a better way to format? I am using dreamweaver and it doesn't seem to format php very well..What do you use?

Comment: @KJThaDon, I tend to manually format as I go, and try not to nest more than a couple of levels if possible.  Sadly there isn't a built in formatter for Php.   It's a case of each to their own.  There are libraries, online tools and extensions available for some editors.  An editor may have PHP language support and help with syntax, when reading and writing.